# Django, override template block conditionally

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% extends "Flow/base.html" %}

{% if no_tracking %}
    {% block head %}
        {% include "Flow/common/tracking/disabled.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

The snippet of code aboves overrides the `head` block in `base.html`, even though `no_tracking` is `False`. How can I make this behavior conditional?

I thought of this:

```
{% block head %}
    {% if no_tracking %}
        {% include "Flow/common/tracking/disabled.html" %}
    {% else %}
    <!-- How can I get "head" of base.html here? -->
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

But this would also override the `head` of `base.html`.

`head` of `base.html` is not empty, it contains scripts that must be on the page when no_tracking is False.

I could override them in `base.html`, but `base.html` has no concept of `no_tracking` since that is a context variable passed to the view being rendered and not the one it extends.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [**`{{ block.super }}`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) to obtain the content that is rendered by the "parent" block:

> If you need to **get the content of the block from the parent template, the `{{ block.super }}` variable** will do the trick. This is useful if you want to add to the contents of a parent block instead of completely overriding it. Data inserted using `{{ block.super }}` will not be automatically escaped (…), since it was already escaped, if necessary, in the parent template.

So here we can use it to add some "extra content" to the block:

```
{% block head %}
    {% if no_tracking %}
        {% include "Flow/common/tracking/disabled.html" %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Man, you're like a Django-god... if I google "Django docs" it should say "were you looking for 'Van Onsem' instead?". Thank you! Will accept asap.